# Cannot copy, would hang every time I do Ctrl+C

Tags: clipboard, clipboard-manager

Recently I cannot copy. Every time I select a text and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it, the process would hang and eventually crash. I even tried with a clipboard manager (qlipper, xfce4-clipman, clipit) but none of them worked.

Edit1: It happens when I try to copy something from a Source Game.

Comment: What is a *"Source Game"*? Do <Ctrl>+C and <Ctrl>+V work here inside your browser?

Comment: Basically if I copy something from it and paste it somewhere else, it would hang. If I try to overwrite that by copying something else, it would hang.

Comment: What is "source game"? What happens I'd you reboot, never use " source game " and use Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v here in the browser? This is important to find out if it is a system wide problem or related to "source game" only.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Team Fortress 2, Counter-Strike (GO, Source), Half-Life 2, ...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a couple of times when Matlab or Octave are installed on Ubuntu.

Check if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> hotkey combination has been assigned to do another task.

Go to:

`System` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts`

Then scroll through the list and check if there's anything with Ctrl+C

Comment: I use Pure Openbox. Checked `rc.xml` and found nothing.